# Можно ли преобразовать std::vector<BYTE> в array<System::Byte>^ без копирования?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

Есть нативный std::vector. Нужно преобразовать его в управляемый тип array^. Тот вариант, который нашел на SO это использовать копирование через: System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy.

Проблема в лишнем копировании (особенно когда вектор много весит, это двойной расход памяти получается), можно ли от него хоть как то уйти? Как то обернуть вектор в массив и возвратить его уже в управляемом виде, или может другие варианты возможны?

Answer (score 2):

Нет, это невозможно в том виде, в котором вы просите.

Дело в том, что `array<T>^` — это управляемый тип, и он должен лежать в управляемой памяти. А память `std::vector` лежит в неуправляемой памяти, так что её нельзя повторно использовать для управляемого массива.*

Самое лучшее, на мой взгляд, решение — отказаться от `array<T>^`, и написать свой тип-обёртку с кастомной индексацией.

```
ref class ArrayWrapper
{
    std::vector<BYTE>& data;
public:
    ArrayWrapper(std::vector<BYTE>& data) : data(data) { }

    property int Count { int get() { return data.size(); } }
    property int default[int]
    {
        int get(int index)
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= data.size())
                throw gcnew System::IndexOutOfRangeException();
            return data[index];
        }
    }
};
```

Если вам нужно имплементация `IEnumerable<System::Byte>` или `IList<System::Byte>`, её удобнее будет сделать в C# в ещё одной обёртке. (Ну или в том же классе `ArrayWrapper`, если очень хочется. Но будет менее удобно.)

---

*Можно, конечно, придумать кастомный аллокатор, который разместит данные `std::vector` в управляемой памяти, и зафиксирует её, чтобы избежать перемещения сборщиком мусора. Но это не лучший вариант, т. к. код выйдет довольно сложный, да и закреплённая память будет мешать сборщику мусора.